# Windows 2012R2 IPAM for managing public IP address

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipam, windows

We are testing IPAM for managing a relatively small network with 5 sites.

The main goal is actually managing the public IP address of each site.

We were able to create the "IP Address Block" for one of the public IP address ranges.

It supposedly scans it, and it only finds 1 public IP Address being used (out of about 8 that respond to ping).

**Is there anyway to get IPAM to recognize the public IP Addresses being used?.**

BTW: I haven't been able to find an use-case/article talking about IPAM and public IP addresses. All of them talk about managing multi-site private IP ranges.

Comment: This whole document contains several references to public IPs, but doesn't seem to treat them any differently than private IPs.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj878303.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I guess my issue is that I do not know how IPAM determines that a given IP address is used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some quick reading, if these addresses are static, then you probably have to record them into IPAM yourself. It will only track things that it knows about via managed DHCP, DNS, and NPS servers, and via static entries that you record.

Think about it this way - how *else* would IPAM know about what addresses are in use? It's not a network scanning tool, and those tools won't work unless their particular scanning method is allowed through your firewall(s).

http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2012/07/05/holistic-administration-of-ip-address-space-using-windows-server-2012-ip-address-management.aspx

> IPAM makes static address management really simple. You can not only
>   see addresses in use, where they are in use, and utilization of the
>   static address space, but you can also find the next available static
>   address, mark it as assigned to a particular device, and update the
>   DNS record corresponding to that device – all from the IPAM console.

Comment: I think that you are correct. I hoped it would at least try to ping the addresses (which wouldn't be perfect, but would be an start).

Comment: Did you find anything in the implementation guide or other documentation that indicates that would happen?

Comment: No - that was just an expectation, and also misunderstanding of the product.

Comment: Hey, it happens. At least it's free